# Combining the history of two git repositories

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I have git repo A. I also have git repo B, which is taken at some commit of repo A, but with the .git folder deleted and remade with `git init`. Some commits have been made in B. I now want to combine A and B, so that A is the one that starts, then at the end, B's history begins. I don't care about the hashes/parents/linking/etc. of the commits on B staying the same, I just need the commit messages and file changes on B to stay the same, when combining the two repositories.

EDIT: Through some searching, I found this:

```
git clone B
cd B
git remote add old A
git remote update
git merge --strategy-option ours --allow-unrelated-histories <commit from when you forked>
git push --force
```

However, this creates a `Merge commit`, which is "dirty" to me -- I want something linear.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way:

```
git clone B
cd B
git remote add old A
git remote update
git rebase -i old/master  --strategy-option theirs --onto <commit of A you want to merge into B>
git push -f
```

Comment: I'd be very cautious about using `--strategy-option` for a long sequence of cherry-picks such as that produced by rebase. But this is indeed a way to do what you want. Consider also using `git graft` followed by filter-branch or filter-repo, though.

Comment: @torek Is there a better way (this is non-intuitive -- I though `rebase` should take the fork and "graft" (not `graft`) it onto the old).

Comment: Oops, I dropped some text in my comment, that should read `git replace --graft`, not `git graft`. The problem, if it is a problem, with `git rebase` is that it has a different *intended goal* and hence doesn't try the easier idea of just preserving each rebased commit's snapshot. It also linearizes commit graphs, although the relatively new `git rebase -r` can preserve "branchiness" (not really a word, branch-y-ness, branch-osity? anyway, the graph structure). But it's a power tool for doing repeated cherry-picking, and that's like using an atom bomb for swatting flies, as some might put it.

Comment: The `git replace` command, with the `--graft` option, can be used to artificially and temporarily join two histories. The problem with *this* (again with the caveat *if it is a problem*) is that replacement grafts don't carry across clones. But they do carry through filter-branch / filter-repo by default, so doing an otherwise no-op filter ("keep all commits as is") has the side effect of making the temporary graft permanent and clone-able.

Comment: The `filter-*` commands are *also* very high powered tools, but in this case we use them in a "low power mode" ("do literally nothing to the commits as you copy them"). It might be nice to have this packaged together into a user-friendly, user-facing command—the filtering commands do not qualify as such—but the need for this kind of repository surgery is rare, so farming it out to specialized surgeons is pretty reasonable.